# Is $H_0^1(\Omega)\subset C(\Omega)?$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

For functions in $H_0^1(\Omega),$ can we say they are countinuous almost everywhere?

For distribution $u\in H_0^1(\Omega),$ $u,\partial_iu\in L^2(\Omega).$ If $n=1,$ $\Omega=(0,1),$ I think we can define $\tilde{u}(x):=\int_0^x \partial udy$ and argue that $\tilde u=u$ in $\mathscr{D}'$ sense. Here $\partial u\in L^2(\Omega)\subset L^1(\Omega)$ and $u\in C(\Omega).$

For $n\ge 2,$ maybe we can use $\partial_i\partial_j=\partial_j\partial_i$ for functions in $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ to define $\tilde{u}$ similarly.

Is my argument correct?

Comment: Have you heard about the Sobolev embedding theorem(s)? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality

Comment: @Thomas $\frac{n}{p}-m=\frac{n}{2}-1\ge 0$ here, what can we do?

Comment: In general, for $n>2$, not much. For $n=2$ there is a short section in that wiki page telling you you are in BMO. Depending on the context you may be able to obtain better results. If you are, e.g., looking at solutions of (elliptic) PDE, then you may be able to  get additional regularity from that information.

Comment: Also note that continuous a.e. is not the same as coinciding with a continuous function a.e. For example, the characteristic function of the rational numbers coincides with the constant function $0$ a.e., but it is nowhere continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, if your integrability exponent is high enough then you have Hölder continuity (in one dimension the threshold is $p=1$ so everything's fine there). However, if your exponent is low, then you can't expect something like that.

In what follows we'll assume $n>2$ for simplicity; in the case $n=2$ use a variant of $\ln\ln(|x|)$ instead of $\ln(|x|)$.

Consider $f(x)=-\eta(x)\ln(|x|)$, where $0\leq \eta\in C_c^\infty(B(0,1/2))$ with $\eta \equiv 1$ in $B(0,1/4)$. Let $(p_k)$ be an enumeration of the rationals in $\Omega$ and define
$$
u(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}f(x-p_k).
$$
Notice that $u$ is well defined, as an element of $H^1$, since the series is absolutely convergent in $H^1$ by translation invariance and the triangle inequality. You can also check that the series converges absolutely a.e. but clearly such a function can't be continuous a.e. or a.e. equal to a continuous function (it's unbounded on every open set of $\Omega$!).

As a fun sanity check: Given $\varepsilon>0$ what is the set $E$ given by Lusin's theorem? i.e. such that $|\Omega\setminus E|<\varepsilon$ and $u|_E$ is continuous.

If you're into this stuff, you can improve Lusin's theorem for Sobolev functions by replacing the Lebesgue measure in the statement above by a quantity that we call, in this case, the $2$-capacity of $\Omega\setminus E$. In this case we say that $u$ has a quasi-continuous representative. But again, even this improved Lusin's theorem is not enough to give the a.e. continuity.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I want.